# How to merge my root partition with unallocated space

Tags: gparted, disk, resize

I have installed Debian as a pure installation in the whole disk. After that I installed another linux distribution alongside Debian. This installation split up my drive in two drives sdb1 and sdb2 with the swap on sdb2. Now I have removed the second linux and need to merge this free space to Debian. I tried with GParted LiveCD but even though the unallocated space is after the root partition it does not give me the chance to extend the root probably because the unallocated space is on the another drive, i.e. sdb2. Here is the picture of my paradox!
[image]
I know similar kind of questions were asked and I have read them all but still can't menage this problem of mine so please someone help!

Comment: You need to resize your extended partition (/dev/sdb2) first before you can add size to /dev/sdb1.  Do all this from a LiveCD so no partitions are mounted.  If you see the key, right click and unmount first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't proceed unless you have a backup, in case it all goes south on you.

First, it looks like you actually have 1 physical drive `/dev/sdb` that is partitioned into two drives.

Second, deactivate the swap `/dev/sdb5`. right click on the `/dev/sdb5` line, and choose deactivate/disable swap.

Third, delete the `/dev/sdb5`, finally deleting the extended partition.

This should then allow you to resize your `/` root partition.

Leave enough space to add the swap drive back.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked as a charm. I just did what you said, the GRUB was OK, no need of reinstalling it!